# How to add object to list item in c#

Tags: c#, linq, list, object

I have following classes:

```
public class QualifyResponse
{       
    List<ProviderQualifyResponse> _providerList = new List<ProviderQualifyResponse>();

    public List<ProviderQualifyResponse> ProviderList
    {
        get { return _providerList; }
        set { _providerList = value; }
    }
}

public class ProviderQualifyResponse
{
    private string _providerCode = string.Empty;

    public string ProviderCode
    {
        get { return _providerCode; }
        set { _providerCode = value; }
    }

    private List<QuestionGroup> _questionGroupList = new List<QuestionGroup>();

    public List<QuestionGroup> QuestionGroupList
    {
        get { return _questionGroupList; }
        set { _questionGroupList = value; }
    }
}
```

I have `QualifyResponse` object which is populated with `ProviderQualifyResponse` but `QuestionGroupList` is empty. Now I want to fill `QuestionGroupList`. When I try to do it like this:

```
QualifyResponse qualifyResponse = response;
qualifyResponse.ProviderList.QuestionGroupList = new List<DataTypes.BuyFlow.Entities.QuestionGroup>();
```

I get error:

> System.Collections.Generic.List' does not
>   contain a definition for 'QuestionGroupList' and no extension method
>   'QuestionGroupList' accepting a first argument of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I add a `List<QuestionGroup>` to my `qualifyResponse.ProviderList`?

Comment: Add also `QuestionGroup` model class

Comment: Your code sample does not make sense, QualifyResponse.QuelifyResponse? There is no such field or method.

Comment: `_providerList` is an empty list, and you're attempting to operate on the list, not its members. You must first add an item to that list, and then work on a specific element in the list, e.g. `qualifyResponse.ProviderList[0].QuestionGroupList = new List<DataTypes.BuyFlow.Entities.QuestionGroup>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that QuestionGroupList is property of class ProviderQualifyResponse and if you want to add List, you need to assign it to property of object. 
Example how to do that for all providers:

```
QualifyResponse qualifyResponse = response;
foreach(var provider in qualifyResponse.ProviderList)
{
     provider.QuestionGroupList = new List<DataTypes.BuyFlow.Entities.QuestionGroup>();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is this expression:

```
qualifyResponse.ProviderList.QuestionGroupList
```

ProviderList is of type List. You'll have to change it so you populate the correct item. Something like this:

```
int index = ...;
qualifyResponse.ProviderList[index].QuestionGroupList = ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that `qualifyResponse.ProviderList` is of type `List<ProviderQualifyResponse>`, you are trying to access `List.QuestionGroupList`, which doesn't exist as the error states.

You'll either need to iterate through the instances in the list to access the instance properties, if that's your intention, or select an instance from the list you wish to instantiate.

```
QualifyResponse qualifyResponse = response;
foreach (var providerQualifyResponse in qualifyResponse.ProviderList)
{
    providerQualifyResponse.QuestionGroupList = new List<DataTypes.BuyFlow.Entities.QuestionGroup>();
}
```